# Laravel Facade class not loading root class instead returns method not found

Tags: php, laravel, facade

I am trying to get my Facade class to work, however it seems Laravel is calling the method on my Facade class instead of calling it on my root class. So I get method undifined error. When I create the the feed class directly from the binding ( App::make('feed')->addArticle();) it works. So I think there is soemthing wrogn with my Facade. Any ideas? Thank in advance.

Controller

```
class RssController extends BaseController 
{

    public function getArticles() {
         Feed::addArticle();
    }
}
```

ServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;



class FeedServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  {    
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('feed', function()
        {
            return new Feed;
        });
    }
}
```

Facade class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class FeedFacade extends Facade {

 protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
 { 
    return 'feed'; 
 }

}
```

Root Class

```
class Feed {

//vars


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function make() {
        return new Feed();
    }

    public function addArticle() {
        return '@addArticle';

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be you want both your Laravel Facade (`Feed::`), and the implementation class of your service provider (`class Feed`) to have the same name.  Facades work because in `app/config/app.php` there's an alias section

```
'aliases' => array(
    'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
```

This aliasing means whenever you use, say, the `App` facade

```
`App::someMethod`
```

Laravel actually invokes the `getFacadeAccessor` on `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App`.  There's no global class `App` in the system.  If there were it would cause a similar problem with the facade.

Get an alias for `Feed`=>`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade\FeedFacade` into your system, and get your implementation class `Feed` out of the global namespace (moving the file to an appropriate place)

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace;
class Feed
{
}
```

...

```
return new \My\Namespace\Feed;
```

and you should be all set.

Also, at the risk of confusing you, you don't need to drop your own classes in the `Illuminate\Etc\...` namespace, and you should probably put them in your own unless you're trying to get the core Laravel team to accept your classes as the official feed service.